Create sortable, ordered, and grouped data from @Query in SwiftData
I've been trying to wrap my head around a sorting and grouping process for a SwiftUI app I've been trying to build.
All the tutorials I've seen have been fairly "basic" when it comes to the sorting and filtering aspect - particularly when using SwiftData.
What I wanted to incorporate was not only sorting by one of the attributes and forward/reverse, but also grouping the data too.
For example, this is code from the Earthquake project by Apple (some items removed for brevity):
struct QuakeList: View {
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var quakes: [Quake]

    init(
        sortParameter: SortParameter = .time,
        sortOrder: SortOrder = .reverse
    ) {
        switch sortParameter {
            case .time:
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: sortOrder)
            case .magnitude:
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.magnitude, order: sortOrder)
        }
    }

What they do in this is pass in the sortParameter and the sortOrder to this view and it re-renders the view on change/update.
How can I expand this so it also can handle grouping so the quakes variable would really be a multidimensional array or even a dictionary.
For example, I was trying to do this to perform the rendering:
enum GroupOption { // New grouping for Section
    case time
    case magnitude
    case none
}

struct ListScreen: View {
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var quakes: [Quake]
    @State private var groupedQuakes: [[Quake]] = [] // New multidimensional array

    init(
        sortParameter: SortParameter = .time,
        sortOrder: ComparisonResult = .orderedAscending, // using ComparisonResult to store the enum value in defaults
        sortGrouping: GroupOption = .none
    ) {
        switch (sortParameter, sortOrder) {
            case (.time, .orderedAscending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: .forward)
            case (.time, .orderedDescending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: .reverse)

            case (.magnitude, .orderedAscending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.magnitude, order: .forward)
            case (.magnitude, .orderedDescending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.magnitude, order: .reverse)

            default:
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: .forward)
        }

        switch sortGrouping {
            case .time:
                groupedQuakes = Dictionary(grouping: _quakes.wrappedValue, by: { $0.time })
                    .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
                    .map({ $0.value })
            case .magnitude:
                groupedQuakes = Dictionary(grouping: _quakes.wrappedValue, by: { $0.magnitude })
                    .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
                    .map({ $0.value })
            case .none:
                groupedQuakes = [_quakes.wrappedValue]
        }
    }

Except, when I use it in the view body it is empty. So switching from the // 1 to // 2 makes the array of data return empty.
// 1
List(quakes) { quake in
  QuakeRow(quake: quake)
}

// 2
List {
  ForEach(groupedQuakes, id: \.self) { group in
    Section {
      ForEach(group) { quake in
        QuakeRow(quake: quake)
      }
    } header: {
      groupHeader(for: group)
    }
  }
}
// ...
func groupHeader(for group: [Quake]) -> Text {
  guard let group = group.first else { return Text("Unknown") }
  switch groupOption {
    case .time:
      return Text(group.time.formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted))
    case .magnitude:
      return Text("\(group.magnitude)")
    case .none:
      return Text("All quakes")
  }
}

So when I return the general @Query private var quakes: [Quake] there is an array returned with the data.
Using the sorting included in the Apple test project the quakes are sorted correctly.
As soon as I try to add in grouping and sort that data returns blank arrays.
Is there something I'm overlooking?

You need to make groupedQuakes into a computed property that does the grouping or if you want a more dynamic solution a function that performs the grouping and that you call when quakes changes.

I think you need to fallback to @SectionedFetchRequest until they add something equivalent to SwiftData. Btw you can set the sort and predicate in body so don't need to implement an init and have the params as lets, it is non-mutating.

Okay so after a bit more research the current status is there is no SwiftData solution at present.
There are however two methods of achieving this though - computed variable (as suggested by Joakim Danielson) and a Swift package.
Computed Variable
In the example code for the ListScreen we move the switch sortGrouping { ... } into a computed property, and add in a @Binding for the current property to assign the multidimensional array to:
struct ListScreen: View {
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var quakes: [Quake]

    @Binding var sortGrouping: GroupOption // <-- new binding
    private var groupedQuakes: [[Quake]] { // <-- new computed property
        switch sortGrouping {
            case .time:
                groupedQuakes = Dictionary(grouping: _quakes.wrappedValue, by: { $0.time })
                    .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
                    .map({ $0.value })
            case .magnitude:
                groupedQuakes = Dictionary(grouping: _quakes.wrappedValue, by: { $0.magnitude })
                    .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
                    .map({ $0.value })
            case .none:
                groupedQuakes = [_quakes.wrappedValue]
        }
    }

    init(
        sortParameter: SortParameter = .time,
        sortOrder: ComparisonResult = .orderedAscending, // using ComparisonResult to store the enum value in defaults
        sortGrouping: Binding<GroupOption>
    ) {
        _sortGrouping = sortGrouping // <-- assign the Binding

        switch (sortParameter, sortOrder) {
            case (.time, .orderedAscending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: .forward)
            case (.time, .orderedDescending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: .reverse)

            case (.magnitude, .orderedAscending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.magnitude, order: .forward)
            case (.magnitude, .orderedDescending):
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.magnitude, order: .reverse)

            default:
                _quakes = Query(sort: \.time, order: .forward)
        }
    }

Then when the sortGrouping changes in the @Binding the view will re-render, grouping your data.
I'm not sure how it will go with overly complex cells, but it works for about 200 cells with an image, headline, and sub-headline without any real noticeable lag.

Swift Package - SectionedQuery
Fairly explanatory README file, but the only thing I couldn't see was having different group types. From what I was briefly testing, you can only set one type and use that as the group meaning that your grouping is fairly fixed.

has anything changed with iOS 18?
